# Removing Orphan Pull merge replication subscriptions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a merge replication set where I have removed one of the pulled subscriptions. On the subscriber the subscription shows up after deletion. It will not go away. I tried the methods provided on many forums but cannot seen to get this to go away and let me recreate. Any suggestions would be much appreciated

> SQL Server could not create a subscription for Subscriber ''.
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> You must first drop all existing merge publications to add an
>   anonymous or local subscription to database '' Changed database
>   context to ''. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 21258)